# ggplot2: POSIXct axis - make sure first major break occurs before any minor break

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

In `ggplot2` there is a default behaviour that has always seemed a little odd to me and which I find frustrating and can lead to plots that are harder to read than they should be. Basically it doesn't not seem to be the default that there is a major break before a minor break, which seems particularly strange if they are both on round numbers (i.e. both middnight of a date). This can mean that for say a 6 day plot window there isn't a date label until 2.5 days into the plot.

So I am looking for an automated way that would work with plots of all lengths to make sure the first break point is always major so that labels aren't starting ~ a third of the way across the plot.

For example in [my first plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dq2x1.png) the automatic breaks are in black and I would like them to be at the points shown in red, so that the first full day of data has a date label. I thought maybe it was an even/odd day thing but the same thing happens if I move my data by a day.

The intent is that my plots will be made in there own function which can be fed data of events which are anywhere from few hours to several weeks so I do not want to hard code any breaks or anything like `date_breaks = "1 day"` as I want it to work for any plot window.

Similarly, for data that only goes a few hours the first label can be almost half way along the axis as in [my second plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tf0CA.png). Here the default minor breaks are 1.5 hours so it doesn't make sense to just swap major and minor breaks but it would be better to have breaks at 10:00, 13:00 or 10:00, 12:00, 14:00,16:00

Here is reprex to make both my example plots

```
library(ggplot2)
#first plot
testdf <- data.frame(DateTime = seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct("2018-03-24 10:00"),
                 by = "hour", length.out = 150),y = rnorm(150))
ggplot(testdf, aes(x = DateTime, y = y))+geom_point()+scale_x_datetime()
#second plot
testdf2 <- data.frame(DateTime = seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct("2018-03-25 10:00"), 
                by = "min", length.out = 360),y = rnorm(360))
ggplot(testdf2, aes(x = DateTime, y = y))+geom_point()
```

[image: my first plot] 
[image: my second plot]

Comment: Hi, for me its not clear if you are happy with `date_breaks = "1 day"` result or if it should be still different from it? 
Because if you are you could write some function which checks the time difference and returns hour/day/month and custom labels.

Comment: I'm happy with the default number of breaks, I just want the labels to start closer to the left hand side of the plot. I don't want to hardcode `date_breaks = "1 day"` as this will not work if my plot window is ~ < 2 days or more than ~ > 7 days

Comment: I have to suggestions. One would be to make your own break sequence, the problem is it messes up your labels. the second would be if{}else{} where you put your data in and when first and last date are with 24h make it hourly, bigger daily and still bigger monthly. I have both working but not sure if it would help with your problem.